# Gmail API - Listing messages does not work with some queries

Tags: python, gmail-api

Took the script that was included with the quick start guide and after the initial setup everything seemed to be working fine. Tried to use the ListMessages function that they included in the docs and depending on the query I use I receive a different response than when I use the testing version on the web. For instance

```
messages = ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, 'me', query=' from:-me')
```

works just fine,
however

```
messages = ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, 'me', query='after:1504748301 from:-me')
```

does not work in that I recieve no messages back. Online I recieve 22 messages

Similarly this does not work either:

```
messages = ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, 'me', query='is:unread from:-me')
```

I thought maybe it was my scope so I've been deleting my credentials and trying out different scopes to no avail.

Full Script Included below

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from apiclient import errors
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
import time
import base64
import email

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# in folder
SCOPES = [
    'https://mail.google.com/',
    #'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    #'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    # Add other requested scopes.
]
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
        os.makedirs(dir_path)
    credential_path = os.path.join(dir_path,
                                   'gmail-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def GetMessage(service, user_id, msg_id):
  """Get a Message with given ID.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    msg_id: The ID of the Message required.

  Returns:
    A Message.
  """
  try:
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id).execute()

    print('Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet'])

    return message
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)


def GetMimeMessage(service, user_id, msg_id):
  """Get a Message and use it to create a MIME Message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    msg_id: The ID of the Message required.

  Returns:
    A MIME Message, consisting of data from Message.
  """
  try:
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id,
                                             format='raw').execute()

    print('Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet'])

    msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))

    mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)

    return mime_msg
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print('An error occurred: %s' % error)


def ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, user_id, query=''):
  """List all Messages of the user's mailbox matching the query.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    query: String used to filter messages returned.
    Eg.- 'from:user@some_domain.com' for Messages from a particular sender.

  Returns:
    List of Messages that match the criteria of the query. Note that the
    returned list contains Message IDs, you must use get with the
    appropriate ID to get the details of a Message.
  """
  try:
      response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id,
                                               q=query).execute()
      messages = []
      if 'messages' in response:
          messages.extend(response['messages'])

      while 'nextPageToken' in response:
          page_token = response['nextPageToken']
          response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=query,
                                         pageToken=page_token).execute()
          messages.extend(response['messages'])
          return messages
  except errors.HttpError, error:
      print("An error occurred: %s" % error)



"""Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.

Creates a Gmail API service object and outputs a list of label names
of the user's Gmail account.
"""
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
labels = results.get('labels', [])

"""
if not labels:
    print('No labels found.')
else:
  print('Labels:')
  for label in labels:
    print(label['name'])
"""


messages = ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, 'me', query='after:1504748301 from:-me')
print("Current epoch: " + str(int(time.time())))
for message in messages:
    #print(message)
    actual_message = GetMessage(service, 'me', message['id'])
    print("internal date: " + actual_message['internalDate'])
    print('Delivered-To: ' + actual_message['payload']['headers'][0]['value'])
    print("From: " + actual_message['payload']['headers'][-3]['value'])
    print("\n")

    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When copying the code from the website make sure return messages is not within the while loop

```
try:
      response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id,
                                               q=query).execute()
      print(response)
      messages = []
      if 'messages' in response:
          messages.extend(response['messages'])

      while 'nextPageToken' in response:
          page_token = response['nextPageToken']
          response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=query,
                                         pageToken=page_token).execute()

          messages.extend(response['messages'])
      return messages
```